# Automator workflow not running on schedule

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, automator, calendar.app

I have a workflow set up to download backups of my websites.
The workflow itself works fine, but i am having trouble scheduling it with iCal.
When the iCal event triggers, the workflow opens in automator, but does not run.

I dont understand why it wont run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save the Workflow as an Application, then run THAT with iCal. Opening a workflow does not make it run; that's only for editing the workflow.